# Aligning Output of Select-String in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

When I use `select-string` I almost always want my output aligned, i.e. the file names, the line numbers, and the found text should all be aligned into columns. Visually it is much less distracting and usually allows spotting discrepancies much more easily. As a trivial example I have injected an extra space in the middle file here:

```
PS> Get-ChildItem *.cs | Select-StringAligned -pattern override
---
FileWithQuiteALengthyName.cs  : 34:    protected override void Foo()
ShortName.cs                  : 46:    protected override void  Bar()
MediumNameFileHere.cs         :123:    protected override void Baz()
---
```

Unfortunately, `Select-String` does not do that; in reality it gives this--can you spot the extra space here?

```
PS> Get-ChildItem *.cs | Select-String -pattern override
---
FileWithQuiteALengthyName.cs:34:    protected override void Foo()
ShortName.cs:46:    protected override void  Bar()
MediumNameFileHere.cs:123:    protected override void Baz()
---
```

Is there a way to force `Select-String` to align its output columns?

EDIT:
Oops! I forgot one important part: I would like to also include the `-Context` parameter if possible so one could get an arbitrary number of lines before and after the match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using objects:

```
Get-ChildItem *.cs | select-string -pattern override |
select Filename,LineNumber,Line | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

and it's also fit to export to csv if you decide you want to keep it.

Adding that requirement to be able to also use context complicates things considerably.

```
function ssalign {
begin {$display = @()}
process {
 $_  -split "`n" |
 foreach {
   $display += 
   $_ | New-PSObjectFromMatches -Pattern '^(.+)?:([\d]+):(.+)' -Property $null,File,Line,Text 
  } 
}
end {
$display | 
 foreach {$_.line = ':{0,5}:' -f $_.line}
 $display | ft -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders
 }
}

Get-ChildItem *.cs | Select-StringAligned -pattern override | ssalign
```

Get that New-PSObjectFromMatches function here:
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/New-PSObjectFromMatches-87d8ce87

Comment: Dude yesssssss. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

this maybe:

```
Get-ChildItem *.cs | select-string -pattern override | ft filename, linenumber , line -AutoSize
```

or something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem *.cs | select-string -pattern override |
 % { "{0,-20}{1,15}{2,70}" -f $_.filename, $_.linenumber , $_.line }
```

The values in the first part of the string format `-f` ("{0,-20}{1,15}{2,70}") have to be checked based on the lenght of your matches

Comment: Any thoughts on the added requirement I put in ( my bad:-( ) after you posted your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I am giving the checkmark to @mjolinor for the nice piece of code he provided and the effort he put into it. Nonetheless, some readers may find this variation of interest, particularly with the NameWidth and NumberWidth parameters I provide for formatting flexibility:

```
filter Select-StringAligned
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [string[]]$InputObject,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
    [string]$Pattern,
    [int[]]$Context = @(0),
    [int]$NameWidth = 35,
    [int]$NumberWidth = 4)

    select-string -Path $InputObject -Pattern $pattern -Context $Context |
    % {
        $entry = $_            

        if ($Context[0] -eq 0) { $offset = 0 }
        else { $offset = @($entry.Context.PreContext).Count }
        $linenum = $entry.LineNumber - $offset - 1

        # For some reason need to special case the $list construction; otherwise acts like Context=(1,1)
        if ($Context[0] + $Context[1] -eq 0) {
            $list = $entry.Line
        }
        else {
            $list =  @($entry.Context.PreContext)
            $list += $entry.Line
            $list += $entry.Context.PostContext
        }
        $list | % { 
            if ($entry.FileName.length -lt $nameWidth) { $truncatedName = $entry.FileName }
            else { $truncatedName=$entry.FileName.SubString(0,$NameWidth) }
            "{0,-$NameWidth}:{1,$NumberWidth}: {2}" -f $truncatedName, $linenum++, $_
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example usage. The -NameWidth parameter allows for a field width either less than (truncating) or greater than (padded) the file names.

```
$pattern = "public"
Get-ChildItem *.cs |
Select-StringAligned -pattern $pattern -Context 0,2 -NameWidth 20 -NumberWidth 3
```